# Get url with Perl module WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, cpan, www-mechanize

I've found the following code:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller;
use URI::URL;

my @go_terms=qw/GO:0006612 GO:0045862 GO:0048545 GO:0007568 GO:0046326 GO:0051901  GO:0010524 GO:0006044 GO:0032024/;
my $go_string=join("\n",@go_terms);
my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
my $formfiller = WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller->new();
$agent->env_proxy();

$agent->get('http://revigo.irb.hr/');
$agent->form_number(1) if $agent->forms and scalar @{$agent->forms};
$formfiller->add_filler( 'goList' => Fixed => $go_string);
$formfiller->add_filler( 'cutoff' => Fixed => '0.4' );
$formfiller->add_filler( 'isPValue' => Fixed => 'yes' );
$formfiller->add_filler( 'whatIsBetter' => Fixed => 'higher' );
$formfiller->add_filler( 'goSizes' => Fixed => 0 );
$formfiller->add_filler( 'measure' => Fixed => 'SIMREL' );
$formfiller->fill_form($agent->current_form);

my $request = $agent->click("startRevigo");
```

what I am trying to do is, once `startRevigo` is clicked, I want to go to the following url `http://revigo.irb.hr/toR.jsp?table=1` and download the file it is giving to me. No clue about how to do this, even reading cpan manual.

Comment: This is not a code related problem, the server seems down. Even with firefox you have an error 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not tested!**

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my @go_terms=qw/GO:0006612 GO:0045862 GO:0048545 GO:0007568 GO:0046326 GO:0051901  GO:0010524 GO:0006044 GO:0032024/;
my $go_string=join("\n",@go_terms);

my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
$agent->env_proxy();

$agent->get('http://revigo.irb.hr/');
$agent->submit_form(
    with_fields => {

        goList => $go_string,
        cutoff => 0.4
        isPValue => "yes",
        whatIsBetter => "higher",
        goSizes => 0,
        measure => "SIMREL",
    },
);

$agent->get("http://revigo.irb.hr/toR.jsp?table=1");
$agent->save_content("your_file.r");
```

Comment: `$mech`? What's that?

Comment: @user2979409 Sorry! Fixed it!

Comment: But this is for store information to a file. What i want is to download a file stored at `http://revigo.irb.hr/toR.jsp?table=1`, which is only available after I click `startRevigo`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `LWP::UserAgent` instead

```
require LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;

my $response = $ua->get('http://revigo.irb.hr/toR.jsp?table=1');

if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;  # I am just printing it but you can save it etc
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm

Comment: It throws all the time... `500 Internal Server Error at revigo.pl`, but it must print something, server's OK after you click `startRevigo`.

Comment: This compiles, what does the response look like? Make sure you have these modules installed with CPAN also